# Buzzing noise when opening application windows

Tags: windows-7, noise

This is a very weird problem indeed.
Windows 7 system makes noticeable buzzing noise in the speakers whenever certain apps are open.I have noticed this problem at least with all browsers and Filezilla.
Searched around for a solution but so far have no any clues...

Comment: Which applications? (use "@harrymc" in the answer)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's your operating system. More like your motherboard/hardware. If it's a sound, you can simply turn them off at the Control Panel -> Sounds.

(But I highly doubt it's a Windows 7 sound..)

Comment: this. Onboard soundcards pick up system noise. Running an application, especially when it's cpu and/or disk intensive generates a lot of noise.